# How to change viewController based on device orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, screen-orientation

for the last few days I've been trying to figure out a way to do this:

Change to CollectionViewController if in landscape mode. Change to ViewController if in portrait mode.

Pretty much the way Music app behaves.

The way I did it was to implement viewWillTransitionToSize() in my main portraitViewController class:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let portraitViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("portraitViewController") as! ViewController
    let landscapeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("landscapeViewController") as! beerCollectionViewController

    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape) {
        // In landscape

        presentViewController(landscapeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        // In portrait

        self.navigationController?.presentViewController(portraitViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       //let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: portraitViewController)
       //presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        //Dismiss collectionViewController after switching back to portrait
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Main viewController(portraitViewController) contains a tableview and a searchController that has a searchBar on top.

In storyboard, portraitViewController is embedded in a navigation controller, collectionViewController(landscapeViewController) is on its own.

It runs, but I get the following 2 warnings:

**Attempt to present UINavigationController on ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

**Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (UISearchController)**

Can someone point out what's going wrong here? If there's any tutorial/examples that can be of help I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you so much for your help

**EDIT**: 
Here is the final code that works

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

    // In landscape
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation) {
        let landscapeVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("landscapeViewController") as! beerCollectionViewController
        if presentedViewController != nil {
            if !presentedViewController!.isBeingDismissed() {
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:  {
                    self.presentViewController(landscapeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            }
        } else {
            self.presentViewController(landscapeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
    // In portrait
    else {
        let navC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navID") as! UINavigationController
        let portraitVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("portraitViewController") as! ViewController

        if presentedViewController != nil {
            if !presentedViewController!.isBeingDismissed() {
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:  {
                    navC.pushViewController(portraitVC, animated: true)
                })
            }
        } else {
            navC.pushViewController(portraitVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for those warnings or errors is that there is a delay when dismissing and presenting view controllers and your calls to present and dismiss are overlapping with each other.

The first error reporting that the view is not in the hierarchy means that you are attempting to present a view on your original view controller or navigation controller that is no longer available because another view controller has been modally presented.

The second error regarding loading a view while it is deallocating indicates that the view controller dismissal has not fully completed when another modal presentation is being attempted.

To prevent these problems requires ensuring the dismissals are complete before presenting a new view controller. This can be accomplished by handling the states using the completion handler in the dismiss methods and adding a check on the `isBeingDismissed` state.

Here is some code that accomplishes that:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation) {
        let landscapeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("landscapeViewController") as! beerCollectionViewController

        if presentedViewController != nil {
            if !presentedViewController!.isBeingDismissed() {
                dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:  {
                    self.presentViewController(landscapeVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            }
        } else {
            self.presentViewController(landscapeVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else { // Portrait
        let portraitVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("portraitViewController") as! ViewController

        if presentedViewController != nil {
            if !presentedViewController!.isBeingDismissed() {
                dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:  {
                    self.presentViewController(portraitVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            }
        } else {
            self.presentViewController(portraitVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know why it was throwing those errors. However I noticed when I go back to the portrait view, the navigation bar is gone. Is this because I'm only presenting the portrait viewController, not the navigation controller that the portrait viewController is embedded in?

Comment: You’re welcome. You can get the navigation bar by instantiating it from the storyboard as in `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(" ") as? UINavigationController` and presenting the navigation controller. You may need to add them into your storyboard and connect them to your VC with a show segue. Modal presentations do not use the previous navigation controller stack as far as I know. The alternative is to push/pop view controllers onto the existing NC stack.

Comment: In portrait mode, I declared `let navC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navID") as! UINavigationController`, then used `navC.pushViewController(portraitVC, animated: true)`, and now all warnings are gone. Need to dig more into how to present viewController but I think I get some basic concepts here. Thanks again!

Comment: That's good to hear. I hope you can get it the way you want it. You may also want to check out size classes as another option for handling different views based on orientation. They are not a replacement for really understanding presenting view controllers, like you are doing, as that's more fundamental.